# SQL - Count total bugs open per day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to make a table that contains a row of every date from 01/01/2012 to present and a count of how many bugs were currently open on each date.

This is the data I have, in a table called `Bugs`: `BugID`, `CreatedDate`, `UpdatedDate`, `Status` (status can be open or closed). If the bug is closed, then the UpdatedDate is the day it closed. If the bug is open, then the UpdatedDate is irrelevant because the bug is open to the current date.

I can make a list of the dates, but I don't know what to do from there.

`WITH D AS
 (
  SELECT @RangeStartDate DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DateValue + 1
  FROM D

  WHERE DateValue + 1 < @RangeEndDate
 ),`

Comment: Using D as the main table LEFT join to bugs on createDate>= D.DateValue AND (D.DateValue<=updatedDate OR UpdatedDate is null)

Comment: is there a reason for not having it in rows rather than columns, e.g date column and bug count column, with rows per day?

Comment: @xQbert Do you suggest a SELECT statement to precede that?

Comment: Example in answer below though there's several good options.

Comment: You would get far better performance from a tally or numbers table instead of using a recursive cte. What you have is basically a hidden loop.

Comment: @Tanner Thanks for pointing that out. I meant to write "a row for every date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @bugs table(BUGID int,Createddate datetime,Updateddate datetime,Status char(1))
insert into @bugs
Select 1,'20140101',NULL,'I'
UNION Select 2,'20140102','20140110','U'
UNION Select 3,'20140103','20140110','C'
UNION Select 4,'20140104',NULL,'I'
UNION Select 5,'20140105','20140110','U'
UNION Select 6,'20140106','20140109','C'
UNION Select 10,'20140101','20140110','C'

declare @RangeStartDate datetime
declare @RangeEndDate datetime
select @RangeStartDate ='20140101'
select @RangeEndDate ='20140201'

;WITH D AS
 (
  SELECT @RangeStartDate DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DateValue + 1
  FROM D
  WHERE DateValue + 1 < @RangeEndDate
 )
Select D.* ,
(Select SUM(dd) from
(Select 1 as DD from @bugs b where  b.Createddate<=d.DateValue and ((b.Status<>'C')  or (b.Status='C' and b.Updateddate>=d.DateValue)) ) a) 
from D
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH D AS
 (
  SELECT @RangeStartDate DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DateValue + 1
  FROM D

  WHERE DateValue + 1 < @RangeEndDate
 )
Select D.DateValue, coalesce(count(BugID),0)
FROM D
LEFT JOIN Bugs B 
  on B.CreateDate <= D.Datevalue
 and (B.UpdateDate >= D.DateValue or B.UpdateDate is null)
Group By D.DateValue
```

Intent: Return all dates from d and only those records that match from bugs
where the bug create date is less than the date, bug greater than the updateddate, or if updateddate is null.

Comment: I think you forgot to put conditions near `or` in parenthesis, this will return incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following query

```
;WITH D AS
 (
  SELECT @RangeStartDate DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DateValue + 1
  FROM D
  WHERE DateValue + 1 < @RangeEndDate
 )
 SELECT D.DateValue, COUNT(ISNULL(BugID,0))
 FROM D LEFT JOIN Bugs ON D.DateValue >= Bugs.CreatedDate 
    AND (D.DateValue <= Bugs.UpdatedDate OR Bugs.UpdatedDate IS NULL)
 GROUP BY D.DateValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your CTE for dates, I would use a query like this (I considered that `UpdatedDate = NULL` when the bug is still open):

```
WITH D AS
 (
  SELECT @RangeStartDate DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DateValue + 1
  FROM D

  WHERE DateValue + 1 < @RangeEndDate
 ),
SELECT D.DateValue,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Bugs
        WHERE CreatedDate <= D.DateValue
          AND (UpdatedDate > D.DateValue
               OR UpdatedDate IS NULL)) AS NumberOfBugs
FROM D
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `CTE` you should use the proper function to manipulate date, such as `DATEADD`, to have a code that will continue to work when the data type will be changed to `DateTime2`.

The code is pretty straightforward: pick a date, get all the bugs with a `CreatedDate` before that date and count the ones where the date is after the UpdateDate to have the closed bugs, and the ones where the date is before the UpdateDate to get the bugs that are still open.

The status field is not really needed, as the status of a bug is determined by having the UpdateDate not `NULL`.

```
DECLARE @RangeStartDate datetime2 = '20120201'
DECLARE @RangeEndDate datetime2 = '20120228'

;WITH D AS (
  SELECT @RangeStartDate DateValue
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(d, 1, DateValue)
  FROM   D
  WHERE  DATEADD(d, 1, DateValue) <= @RangeEndDate
)
SELECT DateValue
     , BugsOpen = COUNT(CASE WHEN DateValue < COALESCE(UpdatedDate, '99991231') 
                             THEN 1 
                             ELSE NULL 
                        END)
     , BugsClose = COUNT(CASE WHEN DateValue >= COALESCE(UpdatedDate, '99991231')
                              THEN 1 
                              ELSE NULL 
                         END)
FROM   D
       LEFT JOIN Bugs ON DateValue >= CreatedDate
GROUP BY DateValue
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/40c94/8)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

While at least a couple of the answer already posted seem to work they all continue to use a recursive cte for counting. This is the same thing as using a while loop. It is very slow. I would highly recommend using a numbers/tally table for this type of thing. It will be a lot faster. The way I implemented it here results in 0 reads to generate a table with 10,000 rows.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Bugs') is not null
    drop table #Bugs

create table #Bugs
(
    BugID int identity not null primary key clustered, 
    BugName varchar(10) not null,
    CreatedDate datetime not null default getdate(), 
    UpdatedDate datetime null, 
    IsClosed bit not null default 0
)

insert #Bugs(BugName, CreatedDate, UpdatedDate)
select 'Bug 1', GETDATE(), null union all
select 'Bug 2', GETDATE() - 3, null union all
select 'Bug 3', GETDATE() -5, GETDATE() -3 union all
select 'Bug 4', getdate()-8, GETDATE() - 7

select * from #Bugs

declare @RangeStart datetime = getdate() - 10;

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select DATEADD(day, N, @RangeStart), *
from cteTally t
cross apply
(
    select COUNT(*) as OpenBugCount
    from #Bugs
    where CreatedDate <= DATEADD(day, N, @RangeStart)
        AND (UpdatedDate >= DATEADD(day, N, @RangeStart) OR UpdatedDate is null)
) b
where t.N <= DATEDIFF(day, @RangeStart, getdate());
```

Take a look at the execution plans for this style of counting versus the rCTE.